# Binding to Component Property inside ngFor

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a filter component that is completely separated from the views that contain the data I am iterating over. I can get the filter pipe to work in the following scenario when I pass the value into the pipe using the input element reference:

```
<div class="card-subject">
  <input type="text" #filter (keyup)="0">
  <div *ngFor="let team of teams | filterData: filter.value">
    <h2>{{ team.name }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ team.num }}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above case the input element lives within the component and is simple. However what I am trying to do is have the input live inside its own component as it will be reused for various different types of cards.

```
<card-directory-search-bar></card-directory-search-bar>
<div class="card-subject">
  <div *ngFor="let team of teams | filterData: filter.value">
    <h2>{{ team.name }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ team.num }}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have subscribed to an observable inside the card and am able to get the values typed into the filter input field. I cannot figure out how to get those values passed into the pipe.

Inside the component I have the values being stored in a property as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.search.getChangeEvent()
    .subscribe((value) => {
      this.value = value;
    }
  );
}
```

I cannot figure out how to pass the value into the pipe. I have tried to bind the property inside the ngFor as follows but it does not work

```
<div *ngFor="let team of teams | filterData: {value}">
```

When I update the code as follows I get the error below:

```
<card-directory-search-bar></card-directory-search-bar>
<div class="card-subject">
  <div *ngFor="let team of teams | filterData: {value}">
    <h2>{{ team.name }}</h2>
    <h2>{{ team.num }}</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

And the subscription works well:

[image]

How can I get the updated value into the pipe?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean like `<div *ngFor="let team of teams | filterData: team">`?

Comment: No. In the first example <div *ngFor="let team of teams | filterData: filter.value"> the value that is passed into filter.value is anything typed into the input field. I could be "rich" and that value is used in the pipe to filter the list of items to match the user input. So in the case of "rich" the list items that would show would have "rich" in the text of the name.

Comment: It should work. Could you check if your subscribe method works by adding `console.log("value", value);` to the `.subscribe()` method?

Comment: Can you remove the `{}`s ? Like: `filterData: value"`

Comment: Bingo. That did it. Thank you. Would you like to add this as a response so I can give you the credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the brackets and use the pipe parameter like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let team of teams | filterData: value">
```